# Configure nameservers ZPanel and Dynadot. VPS

Tags: dns

I did:

1) at ZPanel. Domain Management - Domains. Created a new domain.

2) at ZPanel. DNS Manager. Selected domain. Click on Create Records. Get info Your DNS zone has been loaded without errors.

3) at dynadot.com Domains - Name Servers. Register a domain name server. At Host Name enter website address (like: domain.com). At IP Address copy-paste IP address of my VPS hosting provider.

But website is not reachable (waiting ~ 5 hours and website down).

Can anyone configured nameservers using ZPanl? How much time took to get website up?

With `putty.exe` tried `` `dig @localhost domain.com ``

For working website have such info

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.17.rc1.el6_4.5 <<>> @localhost working-domain.com
; (2 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 52720
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 2
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;working-domain.com.                    IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
working-domain.com.             3600    IN      A       123.45.678.177

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
working-domain.com.             172800  IN      NS      ns1.working-domain.com.
working-domain.com.             172800  IN      NS      ns2.working-domain.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.working-domain.com.         172800  IN      A       123.45.678.177
ns2.working-domain.com.         172800  IN      A       123.45.678.177

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Sun Sep  8 12:36:25 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 112
```

But for not not working domain get this

```
[root@myname ~]# dig @localhost not-working-domain.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.17.rc1.el6_4.5 <<>> @localhost not-working-domain.com
; (2 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 47037
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;not-working-domain.com.                        IN      A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Sun Sep  8 12:36:55 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 32
```